# Self-deleting installer in WiX

Tags: wix

I would like my MSI to self-delete after the installation process is complete. How can I achieve this? Anyway to do it in WIX only? Do you have to create a custom action?

For those wondering, this installer is generated on the fly and bundled to a specific configuration. After the installation is complete, the MSI file has no use anymore (the user must download a new installer with a fresh configuration to reinstall).

Comment: I've given up on this. I went as far as creating a custom action and retrieve the path to the MSI. Next step would have been to create a Task in the scheduler to delete the file on successful install event. Instead, I ended up launching the installed application with some parameter indicating it should delete the specified MSI file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to be useful, mainly because the MSI file *is* needed after the install is complete. Rule 31:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/24/605835.aspx

Any kind of repair (automatic or user repair) will require the original MSI file. You're better off deleting it at uninstall time.

In general, the way I've done this type of thing is to get an executable into the user's temp location (don't install it there, copy it there with a custom action) and arrange for it to run and delete the MSI file. Just rely on eventual cleanup of the temp directory to delete the exe. However, it won't be transparent if it requires elevation to do the delete, and popups of unfamiliar programs asking for elevation may get denied.

Comment: I ended up doing something like that: launch the installed application at the end, with some argument asking to delete the specified msi file.